# Upload pictures but don't show an update on the wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

Does Facebook API allow upload pictures (with user's permission) to user's album but don't update user's wall?

Comment: No. It doesn't answer my question. I want to skip updating user's wall and also without getting that activity show up in all his/her friends feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need user_photos or friends photos permission.

ı think this helps.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/'. $ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: @thurgut, sorry it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @tom you dont have to update user wall.
 you dont have to use this: $api=$facebook->api('me/feed','POST',$message);

Answer (score 0):

The `no_story` parameter is what you are looking for:

> *“If set to 1, optionally suppresses the feed story that is automatically generated on a user’s profile when they upload a photo using your application.”*

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos